# acf_form вывод определенного repeater

Tags: wordpress, acf

В acf есть поле repeater (назовем его myrepeater) внутри которого много других полей, во фронтэнде вывожу acf форму для добавления/редактирования.

```
acf_form([
'field_groups' => [2642],
'post_id' => 'user_' . $current_user_id,
'uploader' => 'basic'
]);
```

На странице показывает весь список заполненных репитеров. Как например при редактировании вывести форму только с репитером id=2 (в штмл это `<tr class="acf-row" data-id="row-2">`) и сохранять его, а не все сразу.

```
-myrepeater (1)
 --field 1
 --field 2
 ...

-myrepeater (2) <--
 --field 1
 --field 2
 ...
```

Так же при добавлении, как показать форму только добавления, а не все сразу.